# Codeigniter Query Builder using MySQL and REGEX with word boundaries adds extra space

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, query-builder

With this issue, I would really like to avoid modifying the core files if possible, so a workaround would be extremely helpful.

REGEX works with the 'where' query builder class easy enough, but using the word boundaries breaks it by adding an extra space.

```
function search($searchQuery){
    $sq = '[[:<:]]'.strtolower($searchQuery).'[[:>:]]';
    $this->db->select('column');
    $this->db->from('table');
    $this->db->where('LOWER(otherColumn) REGEXP', $sq);
    echo $this->db->get_compiled_select();
}

search('billy');
```

**Expected result:**

> SELECT `column` FROM `table` WHERE LOWER(otherColumn) REGEXP
>   '[[:<:]]billy[[:>:]]';

**Actual result:**

> SELECT `column` FROM `table` WHERE LOWER(otherColumn) REGEXP
>   [[: < :]]billy[[:>:]]';

This is such a specific issue with a specific stack and I haven't found anybody running into the same issue. I've tried escaping the colons, the <'s, the square brackets, nothing seems to work. Or it adds additional backslashes.

Really any help or direction would be helpful at this point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
function search($searchQuery){
    $sq = $this->db->escape('[[:<:]]'.strtolower($searchQuery).'[[:>:]]');
    $this->db->select('column');
    $this->db->from('table');
    $this->db->where('LOWER(otherColumn) REGEXP ', $sq, false); 
    echo $this->db->get_compiled_select();
}

search('billy');
```

**For Codeigniter v 3.1.6 and MySQL v5.6**

---

Just because Codeigniter adds space before and after `<` when compiling the query, I do not know why but it does. And I have escaped the value for variable `$sq` to mitigate injection Attack or identical. Hence, added third parameter to `where` function as `false` to prevent it from re-escaping and adding spaces.

I have not gone through other versions of codeigniter. I hope this will work.

For more information on MySQL `REGEXP` visit this link: [MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual - Regular Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html)